# Evaluating regular expressions in c++ without library functions

Tags: c++, c, regex

I am asked to write a program to count the regular expression matches in the given string.
Regular expressioncontains only **asterisk(*)** in it.

Ex: the occurance of **aa*b** in **aabaacb** is **2**

Is this code optimized, or are there any methods to optimize the code?
(Code in C++)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

bool match(char * s1, char * s2){
    int i = 0, r = 0, count = 0;

    while (s1[i] != 0 && s2[r] != 0){
        if (s2[r] == '*'){
            if (s2[r + 1] == s1[i]){
                i++; r+=2;
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
        else if (s1[i++] != s2[r++])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int count(char * s1, char * s2){
    int __count__ = 0;
    while (*s1 != NULL){
        if (match(s1++, s2))
            __count__++;
    }
    return __count__;
}

int main(){
    char * s1 = "hellohelohellloshepo";
    char * s2 = "he*o";

    printf("%s in %s : %d", s2, s1, count(s1, s2));
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: If you want to improve working code, you are better off asking at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: As an aside: You should note that `#include<conio.h>` isn't a standard header file, neither for C, nor for C++. You should get a modern compiler if you want to learn the languages seriously.

Comment: Yeahh. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Also the use of `*.h` headers has been deprecated in C++ since 1998. Please use the respective c-prefixed header (`stdio.h` to `cstdio`, etc).